# Why is the Euler characteristic of a torus with four identified points equal to -2?

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

This does not any sense at all

If I take a torus, and take four points $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$ and identify $x_1$ with $y_1$ and $x_2$ with $y_2$, then I get a torus which two "singularities" you could say (or "connected holes")

A torus has one vertex, two edges and a surface. Such a torus with these four identified points has two vertices, two edges and one surface (NOT three vertices, as you can position the point of the original torus as one of those two connected points). So you should get 2 - 2 + 1 = 1

But that's wrong! And I don't know why

Apparently, you simply take here $\chi(T) - \chi(\text{two points}) = 0 - 2 = -2$

But why do we calculate it in this way? The only way I can interpret this equation above is because "you get 2 points out of 4, so 2 points get lost". But the exercise told us to construct a CW complex here!

Comment: I think you have to start with a CW complex that has 4 distinct vertices (which are then identified in pairs) so that the point identification plays nicely with it.

Comment: Identifying two points is the same as adding a line segment (1-cell) between them (up to homotopy). So $+1$ to number of $1$-cells and therefore $-1$ to the Euler characteristic.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek That's interesting. Why is it like that though?

Comment: Assume the space is not crazy. For instance a CW complex with the two points you identify as vertices. Then add a 1-cell between them. Construct a homotopy that contracts this 1-cell to a point say  by pulling the two endpoints to the middle of the 1-cell. You see that at the end of this deformation you have your original space with the two points identified. The contraction was a continuous deformation so it preserves homotopy type. The technical terms to formalize it are probably "homotopy extension property" and the like.

Comment: Easier to imagine than write formally :).

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek But why does it only add one 1-cell (line), and not additionally two 0-cell (points) to the CW complex?

Comment: I assume we start from a sufficiently fine CW subdivision in which the two points we want to identify are 0-cells. Alternatively you can say that the space $X$ with an extra line segment between two of its points lying in the same component is homotopy equivalent to $X\vee S^1$.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I still don't understand. Let's say we have a CW complex of the torus. Inside of the square, we add two points (two zero cells), which are connected with a line (one 1-cell). Those two points are being identified, so the 1-cell connecting them is getting smaller and smaller until the two 0-cells meet each other. For me personally, this means that the Euler characteristic before identifying those two points with each other was 6-5+1 = 2. After identifying them, it's still equal to 2=5-4+1. So shouldn't the Euler characteristic be equal to 2 here, rather than -1?